# How to subset a DataFrame by only a column having multiple entries?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` that looks like this:

```
0     1
C1    V1
C2    V1
C3    V1
C4    V2
C5    V3
C6    V3
C7    V4
```

I wish to subset `df` by only those rows that have multiple values in column `1`, the desired output being:

```
0     1
C1    V1
C2    V1
C3    V1
C5    V3
C6    V3
```

How do I do this?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528078/determining-duplicate-values-in-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask created by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for mark all duplicates as `True`:

```
print (df.columns)
Index(['0', '1'], dtype='object')

mask = df.duplicated('1', keep=False)
#another solution with Series.duplicated
#mask = df['1'].duplicated(keep=False)

print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
    0   1
0  C1  V1
1  C2  V1
2  C3  V1
4  C5  V3
5  C6  V3
```

---

```
print (df.columns)
Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')

mask = df.duplicated(1, keep=False)
#another solution with Series.duplicated
#mask = df[1].duplicated(keep=False)

print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
    0   1
0  C1  V1
1  C2  V1
2  C3  V1
4  C5  V3
5  C6  V3
```