# Radial Basis Function in 3D (facing Singularity Matrix)

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpolation, spyder, matrix-inverse

I am writing a code for 2D RBF Interpolation but facing singularity issue:

> `raise LinAlgError('Matrix is singular.')
>
> LinAlgError: Matrix is singular.`

I have an idea of QR decomposition to resolve this issue but I don't know at which place of code I should write a code for QR decomposition? Ihave removed duplicate points as well!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
#Read the Dataset from Excel File
dataset=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Windows 10\.spyder-py3\Messwerte_FIBRE.xlsx')
dataset=dataset.drop([0])
dataset=dataset.drop_duplicates(subset=['T Heizstation','T GWK','P Presse','Bauteilverzug'])
index1=[1]
index2=[4]
index3=[5]
index4=[9]
x1=dataset.iloc[:, index1]
x2=dataset.iloc[:, index2]
x3=dataset.iloc[:, index3]
y=dataset.iloc[:, index4]
#converting string into array
x1np=np.array(x1,dtype=float)
x2np=np.array(x2,dtype=float)
x3np=np.array(x3,dtype=float)
ynp=np.array(y,dtype=float)
newfunc = interpolate.Rbf(x1np,x2np,x3np,ynp,function='linear')
estimation= newfunc(x1np,x2np,x3np)
estimation=np.array(estimation)
# Write the estimation output in Another Excel file
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'C:\Users\Windows 10\.spyder-py3\RBF_Reg.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('est_output')
row=2
for outputverzug in enumerate(estimation):
    worksheet.write(row,0,outputverzug[1])
    row+=1
#for next column
row=2     
for outputverzug in enumerate(ynp):
      worksheet.write_column(row,1,outputverzug[1])
      row+=1
worksheet.write(0,0,"Predicted Angle Values")
worksheet.write(1,0,"°")
worksheet.write(0,1,"Original Angle Values")
worksheet.write(1,1,"°")
worksheet.conditional_format('A2:A202', {'type': '3_color_scale',
                                         'min_color': "#FF0000",
                                         'max_color': "#00FF00"})
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B202', {'type':'3_color_scale',
                                         'min_color': "#00FF00",
                                        'max_color': "#FF0000"})
workbook.close()
```

Comment: first I'd check for duplicate points in your data

Comment: If there is duplicate points ? then how to manage these duplicate points?

Comment: The order of the matrix of these two variables i.e. x1np and ynp is 201x1. How to check duplicate points and what to do with these duplicate points?

Comment: have a look at [duplicates in Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528078/determining-duplicate-values-in-an-array)

Comment: also learn how to use the search function both your questions have been asked numerous times on Stackoverflow

Comment: I have removed duplicate points but still facing the matrix singularity.!!!

Answer (score 2):

For empirical data with duplicates (or other form of redundancy), the use of smoothing (instead of forcing the interpolation through all points) is appropriate.

Without smoothing, what is worse than duplicates is "incompatible near duplicates" (close in the X,Y plane but markedly different in Z). The "almost singular" point would spoil the result in the vicinity.

`Rbf` has a `smooth` keyword parameter, float:

> Values greater than zero increase the smoothness of the approximation.
>   0 is for interpolation (default), the function will always go through
>   the nodal points in this case.

I designed an example with near-singular points. Try it with different values for the `smooth` parameter.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(99)

x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100)
x[0] = 0.
for i in range(1,len(x)): # Generate clumpy distribution.
    x[i] = x[i-1] + np.exp(-6.*x[i])
y += 2.*np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,4))
ax.plot(x ,y ,'ko')
xi = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 1000)
for smooth in [.01, 1, 100]:
    rbfi = Rbf(x, y, smooth=smooth)
    yi = rbfi(xi)
    ax.plot(xi,yi,'k-')
fig.show()
```