# Python how to find first duplicated items in an numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I encountered a problem when I expected to find the first duplicated items in an array.
For example:

```
array = [a, b, c, b, b, a, c, a]

returns: [True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False]
```

I have tried to use the np.unique function but it either returns unique values or returns indices of unique values.
Is there any function that is able to do this?

Comment: what do you actually want the code to do? and what is your expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining duplicate values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528078/determining-duplicate-values-in-an-array)

Comment: Is you want to use pandas, a Series has a `.duplicated()` function.

Comment: @ChaddRobertson - I think this is not a full duplicate. Only the approach and first step is the same. And it is already mentioned in the question that he got stuck at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You had a good approach with [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html). With `return_index` the information you need is returned.

I augmented your example to show that this works generally independent of the positions of unique values.

```
array = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'a'])

_, i = np.unique(array, return_index=True)
res = np.zeros_like(array, dtype=bool)
res[i] = True
print(res)
```

Out:

```
[ True  True  True False False False False  True False]
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is 100 times faster than my original approach.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s OK to use `pandas`, there is a convenience function called `duplicated()` which can be used on a Series.

Essentially, just wrap the numpy array in the Series constructor, call the (negated) function and return the boolean array as a numpy array.

Example:

```
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'a'])

(~pd.Series(a).duplicated(keep='first')).to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
array([ True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, False])
```