# Find duplicate values in a 2D array column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array with the following shape

(N, 2)
Below is an example of the 2d array I have at hand:

```
[[0,2]
[0,3]
[1,2]
[1,3]
[1,4]]
```

I would like to get all the values in the second index that have duplicates.
In the example above, I would like to have values 2 and 3 returned.

Is there a specific np function for this sort of task?

It seems like it's the opposite of np.unique but I have yet to find a working function for this problem.

Comment: Both, the question and the best answer are duplicated from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528078/determining-duplicate-values-in-an-array/51297779

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining duplicate values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528078/determining-duplicate-values-in-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could index on the second column and use `np.bincount` to find the indices with counts higher than `1`:

```
a = np.array([[0,2],
            [0,3],
            [1,2],
            [1,3],
            [1,4]])

np.flatnonzero(np.bincount(a[:,1])>1)
# array([2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Or for large integers, `np.unique` will probably be a better option:

```
u, c = np.unique(a[:,1], return_counts=True)
u[c>1]
# array([2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like:

```
   arr = [[0,2],
    [0,3],
    [1,2],
    [1,3],
    [1,4]]
    
    from collections import defaultdict
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for item in arr:
        d[item[1]]+=1
    for k, v in d.items():
        if d[k] > 1:
            print(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Counter from collections to perform this task.

```py
z = np.array([[0,2],
            [0,3],
            [1,2],
            [1,3],
            [1,4]])
```

Now you can loop over desired index to check the duplicates.

```py
from collections import Counter
dup = [item for item, count in Counter(z[:, 1]).items() if count > 1] 
print(dup)
```

```
Out[12]: [2, 3]
```